# Не могу реализовать метод дешифровки XOR в JAVA

Tags: java

Задание, зашифровать строку через XOR и записать в фаил а потом прочитать, выполнить дешифровку и вывести в косноль. Метод write реализовал а вот с емтодом read запутался, помогите

```
package Task2;

import java.io.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream("src/Task2/1.txt");
    FileInputStream file1 = new FileInputStream("src/Task2/1.txt");
    XorOutputStream xorOutputStream = new XorOutputStream(file);
    XorInputStream xorInputStream = new XorInputStream(file1);
    String text = "Ура";
    xorOutputStream.write(text.getBytes());
    ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buf = new byte[10];
    int data;
    while ((data = xorInputStream.read(buf)) > 0) {
        bout.write(buf);
    }
    String string = new String(bout.toByteArray());
    System.out.println(string);
}
}

class XorInputStream extends FilterInputStream {
public XorInputStream(InputStream in) {
    super(in);
}
@Override
public int read(byte[] b) throws IOException {
    in.read(b);
    byte[] res = new byte[b.length];
    byte[] bKey = "55".getBytes();
    for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        res[i] = (byte) (b[i] ^ bKey[i % bKey.length]);
    }
    return res.length;
}
}

class XorOutputStream extends FilterOutputStream {
public XorOutputStream(OutputStream out) {
    super(out);
}
@Override
public void write(byte[] b) throws IOException {
    byte[] bKey = "55".getBytes();
    byte[] res = new byte[b.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        res[i] = (byte) (b[i] ^ bKey[i % bKey.length]);
    }
    out.write(res);
}
}
```

Comment: Неплохо бы закрыть файл после записи, также советую открывать файл на чтение только после того как он был записан.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так.

```
@Override
public int read(byte[] b) throws IOException {
    int l = in.read(b);
    byte[] bKey = "55".getBytes();
    for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        b[i] = (byte) (b[i] ^ bKey[i % bKey.length]);
    }
    return l;
}
```

Это все равно не правильно, но в вашем случае должно сработать.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, тема для меня новая, ещё путаюсь в потоках. В консоле выводит ура5555. Видимо есть лишние байты

Comment: Я поправил код немного. Возможно поможет.

Comment: У вас `while ((data = xorInputStream.read(buf)) > 0) {
        bout.write(buf);
    }` неправильно. Надо `while ((data = xorInputStream.read(buf)) > 0) {
        bout.write(buf, 0, data);
    }`

Comment: Спасибо большое!